# Problem loading .usdz into a custom Entity class

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Is there any way to load usdz model to a custom entity class?

I tried to cast the returned ModelEntity to my custom class but it didn't work out.

```
let entity: CustomEntity = try! CustomEntity.load(named: name) as! CustomEntity
```

Comment: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/stored_entities/loading_entities_from_a_file](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/stored_entities/loading_entities_from_a_file)

Answer (score 0):

## UIKit version

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class CustomClass: Entity, HasModel {
    
    let modelName: String? = "gramophone"
    let myAnchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    func loader() -> AnchorEntity {
        
        if let name = self.modelName {
            let modelEntity = try! CustomClass.loadModel(named: name)
            myAnchor.addChild(modelEntity)
        }
        return myAnchor
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let modelName: String? = "gramophone"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let usdz = CustomClass().loader()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(usdz)
    }
}
```

## SwiftUI version:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

class CustomClass: Entity, HasModel {
    
    func printer() {
        print("I'm inside CustomClass...")
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

    let modelName: String? = "gramophone"
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        typealias CustomEntity = ModelEntity
        var modelEntity = CustomEntity()
       
        if let name = self.modelName {
            
            modelEntity = try! CustomClass.loadModel(named: name)    
            let anchor = AnchorEntity()
            anchor.addChild(modelEntity)
            arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        }
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        CustomClass().printer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want to attach transform information (by installed gestures) to my entities for collaborative session. I suppose this pattern won't work in that fashion.

Comment: Please publish it as amother question.